# I know that Setting tab in Member Profile and Settings Page can be disabled, but is this configurable?

Tags: experience-cloud, member-profile

I know that Setting tab in Member Profile and Settings Page can be disabled, but is this configurable?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007XIPqrSAH

We struggle to find any documentation about this or any layout to configure this or change this My Settings tab. Is this configurable?